# Define conditions on a method's parameter

Tags: ruby, methods

I have a method taking only one parameter:

```
def my_method(number)

end
```

How can I raise an error if the method is called with a `number < 2`? 
And generally, how can I define conditions on a method's parameter?

For example, I want to have an error when calling:

```
my_method(1)
```

Comment: You can't put such constraints directly in the parameter definition. You can do a check in the first line of the method's body: `raise :whatever if number < 2`.

Comment: @ndn, I beg to differ. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add [guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928556/programming-style-should-you-return-early-if-a-guard-condition-is-not-satisfied) in the beginning of function and raise an exception if arguments are not valid.  For example:

```
def my_method(number)
    fail ArgumentError, "Input should be greater than or equal to 2" if number < 2

    # rest of code follows
    # ...
end

# Sample run
begin
  my_method(1)
rescue => e
    puts e.message
end
#=> Input should be greater than or equal to 2
```

You could define [custom exception](http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-custom-exceptions/) class if you don't want to use the `ArgumentError`

---

If you are building something like a framework, then, you can make use of meta-programming techniques to intercept method invocations and apply some validations. Refer [Executing code for every method call in a Ruby module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513558/executing-code-for-every-method-call-in-a-ruby-module). You may have to come up with some kind of DSL to express those validations - a typical example of validation DSL is [Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) in Rails.

In summary, for day-to-day use cases, simple `raise` ([or `fail`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811675/what-does-the-fail-keyword-do-in-ruby)) and `rescue` should suffice. The meta-programming and DSL based validations are needed only if you are building a general purpose framework.

Comment: You don't have to call `new`, just pass the exception class and the message, i.e. `raise ArgumentError, "Input should be ..."` (or `fail` according to the Ruby style guide)

Comment: @Stefan Thanks a lot.  I updated the code.  Appreciate the inputs you keep leaving behind on various posts.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to check the condition and raise it inside method body. There's no builtin option like you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
def my_method arg, dummy = (raise ArgumentError, "arg < 2" if arg < 2) 
  puts "arg=#{arg}"
end
my_method 3
  # arg=3
my_method 1
  # ArgumentError: arg < 2
```

Comment: No... Cary... You know this is just evil. (:

Comment: @ndn, in my experience, evil answers are often overlooked.